# Taking Dual of a Linear Program

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Take the dual of the following LP:

min  $x_1 + x_2 + 4$
such that
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\x_2  \end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ 21 \end{bmatrix}$$
where $x_1,x_2 \geq 0$

I rewrote the objective function as $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $ $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2+4 \end{bmatrix} $

I then get the following: 
min $10y_1 + 21y_2$ such that
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\y_2  \end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$y_1,y_2 \geq 0$

Can someone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: We exclude constants (such as $+4$) when taking duals, since they don’t affect the optimization. Also, what is $b$? Furthermore, we typically express the dual of a minimization problem as a maximization problem (of course, this can be changed by multiplying the objective by $-1$, but it’s not clear that’s what you did here).

Comment: Edited my question. Can you check now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *almost* there, but there's a minus sign missing on the RHS of the dual constraints.

As David M. points out, the dual of a max LPP should be a min LPP.  It can be observed that you've replaced the dual variables in

\begin{align}
\max 10 y_1 + 21 y_2 & \\
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\y_2  \end{bmatrix}
&\leq \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
\bbox[yellow,5px]{y_1, y_2 \le 0} &
\end{align}

by their additive inverses

\begin{align}
\max - 10 y_1 - 21 y_2 & \\
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} -y_1 \\ -y_2  \end{bmatrix}
&\leq \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
\bbox[yellow,5px]{y_1, y_2 \ge 0.} &
\end{align}

Then you replaced "$\max- 10 y_1 - 21 y_2$" with "$\min 10 y_1 + 21 y_2$".  However, the negative signs remain in the dual constraints, and you *can't* get rid of them by multiplication with *any* scalar.  Therefore, a *correct* equivalent LP would be

\begin{align}
\min 10 y_1 + 21 y_2 & \\
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2  \end{bmatrix}
&\bbox[yellow,5px]{\geq \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}} \\
\bbox[yellow,5px]{y_1, y_2 \ge 0.} &
\end{align}